# Textile on Ruby. Restrictions? Proxies?

Tags: ruby, textile

1. Can I restrict a specific "rule of conversion" from Textile markup into HTML markup? What should do to prevent such a text to be converted?

   p<. align left
2. Is there a convenient way (maybe by means of Redcloth?) to create a proxy for a Textile -> Proxy -> HTML conversion? In the proxy I'd like to apply the class attribute with a specific value to entered paragraphs. Any ideads/realisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer in brief has been found on the RedCloth F.A.Q. [page](http://redcloth.org/faq).